# Modify timestamp and select current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to be able modify the time stamp from 2020-05-09 00:00:00.00000 to just the date 2020-05-09 "YYYY-MM-DD". From there, I would like to be able to select today's date. I am tracking how many orders are entered per day.

I tried using

```
Select 
convert(varchar,DDCTMS,101) as Entered
from OCRI
```

The date does not change

2020-05-09 00:00:00.00000

Using

```
Select
CONVERT(varchar(10), DDCTMS) as Entered
from Ocri
```

Syntax works from another Stackoverflow post, 2020-05-09 but I am unable to select the current date.

```
Select
CONVERT(varchar(10), DDCTMS) as Entered
from Ocri
Where DDCTMS = curdate()
```

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 21
>   'curdate' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: `curdate()` is MySQL not SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GETDATE()`:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DDCTMS) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

However, if `DDCTMS` doesn't have a time portion then you can leave as it is.

Comment: Thank you so much. the CONVERT(DATE, DDCTMS) works like a charm.   Speaking about the same topic, how would I select yesterdays records without typing the date?

Comment: Try [`dateadd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Carlos. . . Use `convert(date, dateadd(day, -1, getdate()))`.